# Proof If A is open then $\ A \bigcap \delta A=\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, solution-verification

So this is my proof, if someone can help me is right or wrong

We know $A$ is open and $\delta A =\overline{A} \bigcap A^C $ so $A \bigcap (\overline{A}\bigcap A^C)=(A\bigcap \overline{A})\bigcap A^C=\emptyset$ so $A\bigcap\delta A=\emptyset$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but the last step is perhaps unclear: I would've wrote:
$$
(A \cap \bar{A}) \cap A^c = (\bar{A} \cap A) \cap A^c = \bar{A} \cap (A \cap A^c) = \emptyset,
$$
so it's evident from the fact that $A \cap A^c = \emptyset$.

Here is another way to prove the same result: suppose $A$ is open yet $A \cap \partial A \neq \emptyset$. Let $x \in A \cap \partial A$. By definition of boundary, for every neighborhood $N$ of $x$, we have $N \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $N \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$. But since $x \in A$ and $A$ is open, there exists a neighborhood $N'$ of $x$ such that $N' \subseteq A$. But this would imply $N' \cap A^c = \emptyset$, contradicting the fact $x$ is in the boundary of $A$. So it must be that $A \cap \partial A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks! And because is an "if and only if" can you give me an idea for the back?

Comment: @AngelUrielCristobalSalas to clarify: you'd like a proof that $A\cap \partial A = \emptyset$ implies $A$ is open?

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine! Maybe you can add these steps.
Since $A$ is open, we have:

$$\delta A=\overline{A}\setminus\mathring{A}=\overline{A}\setminus A=\overline{A}\cap A^C$$
Then...